# Analysis of CCVS

Tags: circuit-analysis

The below circuit has a flipped CCVS, im trying to determine the value of the resistor R, so using KCL but the problem is that we only have 1 node so 0 equation? or should i proceed with mesh analysis?

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdq77.png]

Comment: KCL  is not very helpful, because all the node voltages are known, or easily found. The voltage at the middlle node will allow both VR and i1 to be calculated.

Comment: @RussellH but is the voltage in the middle equal to \$ 5i_1 \$ or \$ -5i_1 \$?

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI Treat the bottom node as 0 V. That's a choice. But it is a good choice to make. So start with that. Now assign the necessary voltage to the node in the upper right corner. Note that i2 must pass through the 10 Ohm resistor and work out the voltage drop across that 10 Ohm resistor ***and*** its polarity (more positive end is where the current enters.) This tells you the middle node voltage and therefore what 5*i1 must be (also pay attention to the polarity of the 5*i1 source to work out the sign of i1.)

Comment: @periblepsis hello again, well you choose the counter-clockwise direction as a reference sign for the current of the whole circuit -ok lets go with that- if we were to draw the direction of the voltage across the CCVS would it point upward or downards? and what do you mean by polarity or sign?

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI A resistor has both a voltage drop magnitude and also a polarity. The magnitude can be found by taking the absolute value of the current times the resistance. The sign must be arranged so that the positive end is where the current enters, not leaves.

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI: The polarity of 5i is negative because the diagram shows it that way.

Comment: @periblepsis so i_1 is negative and the current going through the CCVS is positive but the voltage across it is negative? so \$ 50-10*10 = 5i_1 \$?

Comment: Thank you all i got it right!

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI The middle top node would indeed be 50 - 10 * 10 or -50, if you assume that the bottom node is 0 V. That much is correct. But if so, and looking closely at the polarity of the middle source, can you decide whether or not i1 is positive or negative?

Comment: @periblepsis i would said that i1 is negative due to the direction of the CCVS it points downward, no?

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI If i1 is negative then 5 * i1 would be a negative expression result. This would then mean that the (-) terminal must be actually more positive than the (+) terminal. Would that match up with the top middle node being -50 and the bottom node being zero?

Comment: @periblepsis yes thats right the top middle node is -50 and the bottom is zero, thats valid right?

Comment: @periblepsis well it has to be negative because you cant have both i_1 and i_2 with positive magnitude

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI The (-) terminal is at -50 V. The (+) terminal is at 0 V. If the (+) terminal is more positive than the (-) terminal then i1 must be positive.

Comment: @periblepsis so what i said here is right? "it has to be negative because you cant have both i_1 and i_2 with positive magnitude " and " i would said that i1 is negative due to the direction of the CCVS it points downward"

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI Sorry. My confusion. I was thinking one thing and writing another. i1 is the current from the +10 V source to the -50 V point. I was thinking about the direction of the current in the dependent source, which is positive if downward and negative if upward. "Simon" writes it as I3 pointing upwards, so I3 as Simon shows it, would be a negative value. But you are talking about i1, which is pointed going from +10 V towards -50 V, so is positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me redraw the circuit with some additional annotations:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvnmRl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've renamed the dependent voltage source to \$V_3\$, for some naming consistency and equations that are easier to read and follow. The current through it will be \$I_3\$, upwards, corresponding to \$-i\$ in your original schematic. The direction if \$I_3\$ is deliberately counter-intuitive, to illustrate why in this case it doesn't matter if I guess current direction incorrectly. I've also named the top-left resistor to \$R_1\$, for readability.

I have been very careful to label everything; all voltage polarities are explicit here, all current directions too. This makes it easy to apply KVL and KCL, avoiding accidental sign errors in the terms of the equations. There are some important points regarding the polarity symbols "+" and "−" that I've used for the voltages across the resistors:

- the polarity of a voltage across a resistor must be consistent with direction of current through it. In all resistors, current enters at the end with the higher potential, and leaves at the lower potential end. To start with, you may not know either current direction or voltage polarity, but you absolutely must label them to be consistent with this principle. For \$R_1\$ above, I've marked the left end as "+" because that is consistent with current entering it at the higher potential end. The same consistency is observed for \$R_2\$'s voltage polarity with respect to current direction through it.
- For the source \$V_3\$, we don't know yet what direction current will flow through it. It may be either a source of energy (delivering energy to the rest of the circuit), or an energy sink (receiving energy from elsewhere). We are forced to guess current direction, unlike with resistors. I've deliberately guessed wrong (upwards), but that's OK. See the next point.
- In the solution you may find that some currents have negative values, or some voltages have negative values. All this means is that you have incorrectly guessed voltage polarity or current direction. The magnitudes are correct, but a negative sign indicates that what you thought was the more positive end is actually more negative by the same amount, or for current, a negative value signifies that the labelled direction is incorrect, and actually that calculated amount of current is flowing in the opposite direction. Unlike for resistors, for current and voltage sources, if current direction or voltage polarity is ambiguous, it is safe to "guess", because the solved values will reveal actual polarity or direction.

Applying KCL to node X is trivial. According to my current direction labels:

$$ I_1 + I_2 + I_3 = 0 \tag1 $$

Applying KVL to the left-hand loop, my thinking goes like this: I if I start at the bottom left, going clockwise, first I jump over voltage source \$V_1\$ and encounter a rise in potential, so I add. Then I cross over resistor R1, and according to my polarity symbols, this will incur a fall in potential, so I subtract. Lastly, I encounter another rise in potential as I traverse voltage source \$V_3\$ (again, according to its polarity labels), so I add. Having arrived back where I started, the potential here must be same as it was when I started, and the overall change in potential around that loop is 0V:

$$ +V_1 -V_{R1} +V_3 = 0 $$

Apply the same principles to the right hand loop, starting at the bottom right, and going anti-clockwise. There's a potential rise (add) across \$V_2\$, a fall (subtract) across R2, and a rise (add) over \$V_3\$:

$$ +V_2 -V_{R2} + V_3 = 0 $$

It doesn't actually matter which direction you travel around the loop, as long as you observe the polarities of the labels. Let's start at X and go clockwise around the right-hand loop. First there's a potential rise (add) across \$R_2\$, then a fall (subtract) of 50V across \$V_2\$, then a fall (subtract) across source \$V_3\$:

$$ +V_{R2} - V_2 - V_3 = 0 $$

If you look carefully you'll see that these last two equations are equivalent, the only difference being that all terms are negated. Simply multiply both sides of one equation by \$-1\$, and rearrange, to obtain the other equation.

Of course \$V_{R1}\$ and \$V_{R2}\$ can be expressed in terms of current and resistance, as per Ohm's law, and substituted back into the KVL equations:

$$ V_{R1} = I_1R_1 $$

$$ V_{R2} = I_2R_2 $$

This yields KVL equations:

$$ +V_1 -I_1R_1 +V_3=0 \tag2 $$

$$ +V_2 -I_2R_2 +V_3 = 0 \tag3 $$

The last relationship is between \$V_3\$ and \$I_1\$, which we know from the current-controlled voltage source. I believe this is the one you failed to account for:

$$ V_3 = 5I_1 \tag4 $$

You have four equations, tagged as 1, 2, 3 and 4 above, and there are four unknown values: \$I_1\$, \$I_3\$, \$V_3\$ and \$R_1\$. All other variables in these equations have known values. Therefore there exists a complete solution for all four unknowns.

Such problems as this only seem difficult when one fails to be disciplined when writing the algebraic relationships. When care is taken, and the bullet points above are observed, the solution is often trivial. In this case it is very trivial; plug in the known values for equation 3:

$$
\begin{aligned}
+V_2 -I_2R_2 + V_3 &= 0 \\ \\
+50 -(10 \times 10) + V_3 &= 0 \\ \\
V_3 &= 100 - 50 \\ \\
&= 50
\end{aligned}
$$

That was super easy; we didn't even have to refer to the other equations to solve this one. To anyone with experience this cheap operation would have been obvious. We know \$R_2=10\Omega\$, and we know the current through it \$I_2=10A\$, so we know the voltage \$V_{R2}=-100V\$ across it. No need for complicated simultaneous equations to know straight away the potential at X with respect to Y.

With a value for \$V_3=+50\$, we can plug that into equation 4:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_3 &= 5I_1 \\ \\
50 &= 5I_1 \\ \\
I_1 &= \frac{50}{5} \\ \\
I_1 &= 10A
\end{aligned}
$$

Knowing \$I_1\$, we can obtain \$R_1\$ from equation 2:

$$
\begin{aligned}
+V_1 -I_1R_1 +V_3 &= 0 \\ \\
+10 -10R_1 + 50 &= 0 \\ \\
-10R_1 &= -50 - 10 \\ \\
R_1 &= \frac{60}{10} \\ \\
&= 6\Omega \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

The last unknown is \$I_3\$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_1 + I_2 + I_3  &= 0 \\ \\
I_3 &= -I_1 - I_2 \\ \\
&= -10A -10A \\ \\
&= -20A
\end{aligned}
$$

This negative value indicates that I guessed incorrectly for the direction of \$I_3\$. In reality it is +20A flowing downwards.

Comment: This is by far the best answer i recieved, deserves it, thank you so much!

Comment: but i think where you slipped is when you said \$ i_2 = 10A , R = 10 \Omega$ and \$ V_{R_2} = Ri_2 = -100 V \$ this what made me confused because you cant have both i_1 and i_2 positive it just doesnt make sense they are both going differently clockwise talking

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI  The I1 and I2 will flow in the direction shown on Simon's diagram. And both of this current will enter into CCVS from the "negative side". And this is why in the Simon's amnswer I3 is negative and equal -20A. Because this "minus" informs us that the I3 current is flowing in the opposite direction than marked (shown) in Simon's diagram.

Comment: @G36 You dont understand my problem is with the sign of I1, it should be negative, they cant be of the same sign simultanuously

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI  Why negative? Do you mean that I1 should flow from node X to V1?

Comment: ah i see my problem now great logic @G36 so treating the current as they are in simon's diagram we have these two KVL equations : \$ 10 = -5i_1  + R_1 i_1 \land 50 = -5 i_1 + R_2 i_2 \$

Comment: And of course you are right that V_R2 should be positive and equal to 100V.